# change config.xml parameters value at run time in Samsung smart TV app development

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

Is there any way to change the parameter value of config.xml inSamsung smart TV app development file at run time 
for example
 on start of app

> `<ticker itemtype='boolean'>y</ticker`>

and once i navigate to another page i want this value to be

> `<ticker itemtype='boolean'>n</ticker`>

Is this possible and if yes then how can this be achieved, any help in right direction will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to do so because it reads the information before entering the application.

No matter for the old samsung and tizen, the environment is not possible to change in run time.